# How to uninstall the libraries in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

In ubuntu 9.10, I execute the following command to download/install the following libraries:

```
sudo aptitude build-dep openjdk-6

sudo aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Can you please tell me how to uninstall the libraries I installed using the above command.

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jdk
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about how to undo 'sudo aptitude build-dep openjdk-6'?

Comment: I believe apt is smart enough to handle deps properly as well. At least it will usually note them. You can also `sudo apt-get autoremove ...` to nuke deps automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre-headless
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I run sudo apt-get remove and apt-get autoremove,get    `Package openjdk-7-jdk is not installed, so not removed`

Answer (score 0):

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep software_name | awk '{ print $1 }'

$ sudo apt-get purge package_name

Comment: Your answer would benefit from an explanaition of why he should use `dpkg` and what the two commands actually do. besides that, using the backtick (`) to highlight the commands would also help...